# Preview Frame from Quicktime Movie

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4

I want to add a UIImage in a tableview that shows a preview frame from a list of quicktime movies that are stored on a server.  I have the URL to the actual movies on the server, but I'm not sure how to grab just one frame of each movie to include in the UITableview.

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

Without actually downloading the file (or at least a portion of it), I don't think it would be possible to grab just one frame of the movie. Perhaps a server side process could generate the poster frames for you, and follow a naming convention to make it easy to extrapolate the poster frame's URL from the movie's URL.

Perhaps this question will help with extracting frames from the movies:

[Export every frame as image from a Movie-File (QuickTime-API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1859415/export-every-frame-as-image-from-a-movie-file-quicktime-api)